# Why isn't 'post' a method of Dataflow.TransformBlock? Doesn't compile

Tags: .net, vb.net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

In [examples on the web](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Async-CTP-TPL-Dataflow-TransformBlock-Tin-Tout.aspx), I see that there is a method `Dataflow.TransformBlock.Post()`, yet I can't get it to compile:

```
Dim q As New Dataflow.TransformBlock(Of Integer, Integer)(Function(x As Integer) As Integer
                                                                  Return x
                                                              End Function)
q.post(5)
```

The error is:

> 'post' is not a member of 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.TransformBlock(Of Integer, Integer)'.

Comment: It might be an extension method in the Dataflow namespace, or there might be a casing issue. Try 'Post' instead of 'post' and try importing the Dataflow namespace.

Comment: @Strilanc AFAIK VB is not case-sensitive, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @svick That's right. I was considering the unlikely possibility of an ambiguity being introduced by the case insensitivity... I guess it would be a different error in that case anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Post()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194836.aspx) is an extension method, which means you need to import the TPL Dataflow namespace:

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow
```

If you do that, you could also remove the `Dataflow.` prefix from the block class name.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194836.aspx) this is only available in .NET 4.5 - perhaps you are using an older .NET version and/or not doing `Imports System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` and/or don't reference `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll` in your project.

Comment: If he was using older version of .Net or missing the reference, he wouldn't be able to use TPL Dataflow at all, so the previous code wouldn't compile either.